# Multiple authentications in one website with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a secured website. The complete website is secured so, regardless of the page you ask, you have to enter the user/password.
I did this with this code in the htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /path/.htpass
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Website"
Require valid-user
```

Now, i want to add another authentification for a specific url. So i tried this :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/myurl require_auth=true

AuthUserFile /path/.htpmyrul
AuthName "Myurl"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

It worked for myurl, but the problem is that this code "cancelled" the first code! So now, my website only ask for authentification when i visit myurl, but if i visit any other url, the website doesn't ask for authentification

Is it possible to have both authentifications work together ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `Satisfy All` instead of `any`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Now the website asks for "Myurl" authentification on all the website. And once i authentifiate and try to visit myurl, i got a 403 forbidden access error.

Comment: You can use two location blocks.

Comment: How do we do that ? sorry, i'm far from being an expert in htaccess configurations :)

Comment: Well I can give an example but if you use the `location` block it has to go in your apache config file or vhost file. It can't be used in htaccess. you'll have to have access to your apache config.

Comment: Ok so there's no solution using htaccess ? i have no access to apache config files ...

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this.

In the main root of your htaccess file put this.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/myurl" require_auth

AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Webiste"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=require_auth
Satisfy any
```

Then create a htaccess file inside `myurl` folder and put this example inside it.

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/other/.htpasswd
AuthName "myurl"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
```

This should allow you to use another htpasswd for your sub folder.

Comment: The problem is that i use a CMS, so myurl, is not really a folder!

Comment: @user, I have the same problem. Have you succeded with this?